# How to create incrementing button in Codeigniter that updates database onclick?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter. I have a project where Admin allots balance to its reseller. Now I  want to create a button in html which provides interface to admin to increment the balance on button click. and when he increments it the value should be also updated in database. Maybe this is very simple but i couldn't do this! I think I should use ajax or Jquery both for this maybe

Below is my code for view :(want to add increment and decrement button besides the balance input )

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<?php echo form_open(); ?>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>SIP Username</td>
        <td><?php echo form_input('sip_username', set_value('sip_username', $user->sip_username)); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>SIP Password</td>
        <td><?php echo form_input('sip_password', set_value('sip_password', $user->sip_password)); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Key</td>
        <td><?php echo form_input('key', set_value('key', $user->key), 'readonly'); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Allocation Block</td>
        <td><?php echo form_input('allocation_block', set_value('allocation_block', $user->allocation_block)); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td><?php echo form_input('name', set_value('name', $user->name)); ?></td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td>Reseller Email</td>
        <td><?php echo form_input('email', set_value('email', $user->email)); ?></td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td>Password</td>
        <td><?php echo form_password('password'); ?></td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td>Confirm password</td>
        <td><?php echo form_password('password_confirm'); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>User_Required</td>
        <td><?php echo form_input('user_num', set_value('user_num', $user->user_num)); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Balance</td>
        <td><?php echo form_input('balance', set_value('balance', $user->balance)); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Phone</td>
        <td><?php echo form_input('phone', set_value('phone', $user->phone)); ?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Address</td>
        <td><?php echo form_input('address', set_value('address', $user->address)); ?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Status</td>
        <td><?php echo form_dropdown('status', array('Active' => 'Active', 'Inactive' => 'inactive', 'Delete' => 'delete'), $this->input->post('status') ? $this->input->post('status') : $user->status ); ?></td>  
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Country</td>
        <td><?php echo form_input('country', set_value('country', $user->country)); ?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Country Code</td>
        <td><?php echo form_input('country_code', set_value('country_code', $user->country_code)); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Save', 'class="btn btn-primary"'); ?></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <?php echo form_close();?>
```

The Controller :

```
public function edit ($id = NULL)
{
    // Fetch a user or set a new one
    if ($id) {
        $this->data['user'] = $this->reseller_m->get($id);
        count($this->data['user']) || $this->data['errors'][] = 'User could not be found';
    }
    else {
        $this->data['user'] = $this->reseller_m->get_new();
    }

    // Set up the form
    $rules = $this->reseller_m->rules_admin;
    $id || $rules['password']['rules'] .= '|required';
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);

    // Process the form
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {



        $data = $this->reseller_m->array_from_post(array('sip_username','sip_password','key','allocation_block','name','email','password','phone','balance','user_num','address','country','country_code','created','modified','status'));


        $data['password'] = $this->reseller_m->hash($data['password']);

        $key=$this->reseller_m->save($data, $id);

    //here we get the last inserted record id in $last_id
        $last_id = $this->db->insert_id();

    //The logic to create blank rows in user table mapped to reseller_id    

        $values=array($this->input->post('name'),$this->input->post('country_code'),$this->input->post('allocation_block'),$this->input->post('user_num'));

        $key=implode('-',$values);

        $this->db->where('id',$last_id);
        $this->db->update('reseller',array('key'=>$key));

            for($i=1; $i<=$data['user_num'];$i++)
            {
            $userdata=array('key'=>$key);
        // here users is taken name of user table with retailer_id is field
             $this->db->insert('users',$userdata);
             }


        redirect('admin/reseller');
    }

    // Load the view
    $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/reseller/edit';
    $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $this->data);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are familiar with ajax, you can use ajax for this.

On click of the button you can call ajax and write code in the controller function to update the value in the database.

Comment: Yes but i dont know how to perform this ajax action

Comment: you can do like this.
Give id to button as update

then add the following code after loading the footer.

    <script>
        $(document).on("click","#update",function(){
        url:"<?= base_url("path_to_your_controller_function") ?>",
        data:{"name":value,"name":value},// pass the required values to controller function
        type:"POST",
        dataType:"HTML",
        success: function(){
            //after success, do the sutff required here
        }

    });


</script>

Comment: can i use something like :<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myNumber").stepUp();
}
</script>
Number: <input type="number" id="myNumber">

Comment: i found this on W3schools .